# What's the limit of compiler optimization? How smart is it?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

People keep telling me instead of writing "shift 1 bit to the left", just write "multiple by 2", because it's a lot more readable, and the compile will be smart enough to do the optimization.

What else would compiles generally do, and developers should not do (for code readability)? I always write `string.length == 0` instead of `string == ""` because I read somewhere 5-6 years ago, saying numeric operations are much faster. Is this still true?

Or, would most compiler be smart enough to convert the following:

`int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    result += i;
}`

into: `int result = 5050;`?

What is your favourite "optimization" that you do, because most compiles won't do?

Comment: There's no way anyone can enumerate every single optimization that a compiler can do. (there's a lot of them) Do you have more specific examples?

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question is not for a particular compiler or a particular algorithm. I want to ask a general question, in hoping to learn some cool code snips from great developers like you guys.

Comment: If you know a bit of assembly, it isn't too hard to see for yourself whether or not a compiler can do a certain optimization.

Comment: But if I do look at the assembly, or IL for .NET, I would still not have thought about writing `string.length == 0` in the first place (assume this optimization actually works).

Comment: `string.length == 0` is not that same as `string == ""` because the former will throw an exception if `string` is `null` and the latter will not. Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algorithms: no compiler on the planet so far can choose a better algorithm for you. Too many people hastily jump to the rewrite-in-C part after they benchmark, when they should have really considered replacing the algorithm they're using in the first place.

Comment: Oh, you'll be surprised... Compilers actually ***can*** (in some cases) recognize what you are doing and choose a better algorithm...

Comment: And to argue the other side, compilers can also be amazingly stupid and miss things that are trivial to a human programmer...

Comment: @Mysticial Can you give an example of a compiler that picks a better algorithm when it recognizes what you are doing? I am not aware of any.

Comment: The most common one is summing up an array. Very trivial - how would an average programmer do it? Add each element incrementally right? There's actually a better way than that... This is so common that most major compilers are able to recognize this pattern and replace it with an alternative algorithm.

Comment: To be pedantic: that's not "intelligently" choosing a "better" algorithm, it's just a common heuristic and pattern matching; a hack of sorts.

Comment: @JoshuaK That seems to me to be a distinction without a difference. Either the compiler has chosen a better algorithm or it hasn't. Constant folding is another example: the better algorithm comprises pre-calculation of calculable constants, an extreme case of code hoisting. And newly introducing the word "intelligently" into the discussion doesn't actually mean anything.

Comment: @Mysticial Do you mean summing up floats in the usual way to keep precision loss low? Or is there really a better single threaded solution to summing up integers (or are you talking about auto parallelization?)?

Comment: @Voo Not with floats because that will break floating-point associativity. But for integers, there's a technique called "node-splitting" which compilers often use to maximize ILP for reduction operations.

Comment: @Mysticial I can't find some short summary for that technique, but I assume from the name and your explanation that it basically doesn't do something like `add eax, dword ptr [ebx]` over the array but instead sums it up into several different registers instead and sums those regs up at the end? Makes sense why this could help. Thanks.

Comment: @Voo Yes, that's exactly what it is. :) It's one of a number of highly specialized optimizations where the compiler "identifies" the task via pattern matching. Then replaces it with a highly optimized pre-coded algorithm written by whoever made the compiler.

Comment: @Mystical: I meant "intelligent" as in the compiler can't choose to implement a better kind of binary tree for the task the program fulfills. It can make minor or major changes to optimize an algorithm, and in some cases change the cyclomatic complexity (loop optimization, etc), but it can't rewrite your program to be smarter.